# Tic Tac Toe logic errors

Tags: php, logic

My program here is a simple tic tac toe game and my winners are not being displayed properly  the only 4 correct ones are the two diagonals and row ones win and column win.The html/javascript is not the problem its just the php.

```
<?php
//Players
$X = "Dalton";
$O = "Joe";
$winner = false;
//game board positoins
$r1c1 = !empty($_POST['r1c1'] ) ? $_POST['r1c1'] : '';
$r1c2 = !empty($_POST['r1c2'] ) ? $_POST['r1c2'] : '';
$r1c3 = !empty($_POST['r1c3'] ) ? $_POST['r1c3'] : '';
$r2c1 = !empty($_POST['r2c1'] ) ? $_POST['r2c1'] : '';
$r2c2 = !empty($_POST['r2c2'] ) ? $_POST['r2c2'] : '';
$r2c3 = !empty($_POST['r2c3'] ) ? $_POST['r2c3'] : '';
$r3c1 = !empty($_POST['r3c1'] ) ? $_POST['r3c1'] : '';
$r3c2 = !empty($_POST['r3c2'] ) ? $_POST['r3c2'] : '';
$r3c3 = !empty($_POST['r3c3'] ) ? $_POST['r3c3'] : '';

if($r1c1 == $r1c2 && $r1c2 == $r1c3 ) {
    $winner = $r1c1;
} elseif($r2c1 == $r2c2 && $r2c2 == $r2c3 ) {
    $winner = $r2c1;
} elseif($r3c1 == $r3c2 && $r3c2 == $r3c3 ) {
    $winner = $r3c1;
} elseif($r1c1 == $r2c1 && $r2c1 == $r3c1 ) {
    $winner = $r1c1;
} elseif($r1c2 == $r2c2 && $r2c2 == $r3c2 ) {
    $winner = $r1c2;
} elseif($r1c3 == $r2c3 && $r2c3 == $r3c3 ) {
    $winner = $r1c3;
} elseif($r1c1 == $r2c2 && $r2c2 == $r3c3 ) {
    $winner = $r1c1;
} elseif($r1c3 == $r2c2 && $r2c2 == $r3c1 ) {
    $winner = $r1c3;
} else {
    $winner = 'Draw';
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
        <!--

            The Javascript code below requires access to the internet to run. If you are
            running this page on a computer with no Internet access, it will cause errors.
            You may delete these lines or modify them if you wish.

            The 1st block in the code below is helping you by not allowing any character 
            except an uppercase 'X' or uppercase 'O'. This is unnessisary, but makes it easier
            for you to process on the PHP side.

            The 2nd block of code is helping you by making any field that already has has 
            'X' or 'O' readonly when the page loads. Extra points will be giving to any student 
            how can replicate this part of the Javascript using only PHP. Simply delete the lines 
            below if you wish to attempt.

        -->
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //  This block of code prevents you from entering anything but X or O
                $('input').bind('keyup',function() {
                    if( $(this).hasClass('button') == false ){
                        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
                        if(this.value != 'X' && this.value != 'O') {
                            this.value = '';
                        }
                    }
                });

                //  This block of code makes the used spots on the grid readonly once used
                $('input').each(function(i){
                    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
                    if(this.value == 'X' || this.value == 'O') {
                        $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('readonly', true);
                        //this.readOnly = true;
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
        <!--   You may do as you please with this CSS code   -->
        <style>
            body * { padding:0; margin:0; }
            .disabled { background: #eeeeee; }
            .button { display: block; width:180px; margin: 10px 0; }
            #gameboard { border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0; }
            #gameboard tr:nth-child(even) { 
                border-top:2px solid black;
                border-bottom:2px solid black;
            }
            #gameboard tr td:first-child { border-right:2px solid black; }
            #gameboard tr td:last-child { border-left:2px solid black; }
            #gameboard input { 
                font-size:50px; 
                width:60px; 
                padding:3px;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--   
            Notice that the default values for each box below is set to '', and empty string. 
            You will have to set them using data from the $_POST, if you don't the game will 
            reset after every move. Something like this for every box maybe ...

            if( !empty($_POST['r1c0']) ) {
                $r1c0 = $_POST['r1c0'];
            } else {
                $r1c0 = '';
            }

        -->
        <form action="" name='game' method='POST'>
            <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='gameboard'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r1c1' value='<?php echo $r1c1; ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r1c2' value='<?php echo $r1c2; ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r1c3' value='<?php echo $r1c3; ?>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r2c1' value='<?php echo $r2c1; ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r2c2' value='<?php echo $r2c2; ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r2c3' value='<?php echo $r2c3; ?>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r3c1' value='<?php echo $r3c1; ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r3c2' value='<?php echo $r3c2; ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' maxlength='1' name='r3c3' value='<?php echo $r3c3; ?>' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php if($winner != '') { ?>
            <h3><?php echo "The winner is ".$winner; ?></h3>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <input class='button' type='submit' value='Finish Move' />
            <input class='button' type="reset" value="Reset Game" />
        <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is correct and what is not?

Comment: I dont get any errors but when i test the opions it wont display the winner when there are 3 in a row in columns two and three and rows two and three but if the three in a row is in rows one or column one then it displays the winner correctly

Comment: At first test, it looks like some of your cells are passing lower case values when submitted. 4 columns pass o's as lower case (r2c2, r2c3, r3c1, r3c2), 3 pass x's (r2c2, r3c1, r3c2).

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like this at the top of your code should make it work. Some of your cells are passing lower case values. You should probably put in some other error checking as Javascript can be manipulated.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $_POST[$key] = strtoupper($val);
}
```

Comment: Also, if you bind your event to `change` instead of `keyup` it will fix the issue of the values being posted as lower case.